# Combining values in one column (or part) when values in another column (or part) match

Tags: list-manipulation, gathering, faq

Consider the following:

```
data={{{3542313600, 175}, {3542918400, 175}}, {{3544128000, 450},
{3544128000, 450}, {3545337600, 450}, {3545942400, 450}, {3546547200, 450}}};
```

whereas the first element of each `{_,_}` represent a date in absolute time, i.e. `{_,_}` corresponds to the pattern `{AbsoluteDate_,Value_}`.

Now I would like to calculate the sum of all `Value_` when the corresponding `AbsoluteDate_` is equal, e.g.

`{3545337600, 450}, {3545337600, 450}`-> `{3545337600, 900}`.

Comment: Do you mind if your list gets sorted?

Comment: No, I don't mind, because I can get the order back to the original one later.

Comment: Looks like there are many ways to skin the cat.

Comment: @David: in *Mathematica*? **Always**.

Comment: @John moving-target questions are generally discouraged.  You should consider posting your update as a new question.

Comment: I changed everything back and posted a new question:
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4379/list-operations-only-when-restrictions-are-fulfilled-part-2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following also works (though its a bit messy to look at) and will probably be faster than pattern matching if you have large input data.

```
Transpose[{#[[All, 1, 1]], 
      Total[#[[All, All, 2]], {2}]}] &[#] & /@ (GatherBy[#, First] & /@
    data)
```

**EDIT:**

I should point out that there are at least a couple of different problems being solved in the answers posted here. The results posted by myself and @RM attempt to preserve the structure of the original data and so do not gather like dates if they are present in multiple sublists.

Answers posted by @David Carraher and @rcollyer ignore the structure of the original data and gather all like dates.

I'm not sure which is the correct approach in this case but it felt worth pointing out the difference.

Answer (score 15):

Here's another one to consider:

```
{#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ GatherBy[Flatten[data, 1], First]
```

`GatherBy...` gathers pairs with the same `AbsoluteDate`.

`{#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@` returns {date, totVal} for each date.

Comment: This is efficient, readable, and terse. +1

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you did not intend to add an extra layer of lists in your data, 
for this type of manipulation, I'm a fan of [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html) and [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html):

```
Reap[ Sow[#2, #1]& @@@ Flatten[data,1], _, {#1,Total[#2]}&][[2]]
(* {{3542313600, 175}, {3542918400, 175}, {3544128000, 450}, 
    {3544732800, 450}, {3545337600, 900}, {3545942400, 450}, 
    {3546547200, 450}, {3547152000, 0}}
*)
```

If it wasn't mistaken, we need to `Map` the above onto each data set:

```
Reap[ Sow[#2, #1]& @@@ #, _, {#1,Total[#2]}&][[2]]& /@ data
(* {{{3542313600, 175}, {3542918400, 175}}, 
    {{3544128000, 450}, {3544732800, 450}, {3545337600, 900}, 
     {3545942400, 450}, {3546547200, 450}, {3547152000, 0}}}
*)
```

Comment: You've got my vote. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard why? `Reap` and `Sow`? Or, the "excessive" use of shorthand? Or, better yet, it's a one liner?

Comment: Reap and Sow only.  You can do better if you're going for terse (`#1` -> `#`, `Total` -> `Tr` at least).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that's true, but sometimes it pays to include the `1` for clarity. :P

Comment: Agreed.  I was simply explaining that if you want to gain my vote on the basis of shorthand it's going to have to be more thorough. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way (partially similar to Andy's solution) :

```
Transpose[{#[[All, 1, 1]], Total[#[[All, All, 2]], {2}]}] &[#]& @ SplitBy[ Flatten[ data, 1], First]
```

or similar to David's solution :

```
{#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ SplitBy[ Flatten[ data, 1], First]
```

Answer (score 6):

For data that is not already grouped by the first element:

```
dat2 = {{baz, 16}, {foo, 65}, {baz, 41}, {bar, 88}, {foo, 2},
        {bar, 96}, {foo, 20}, {bar, 19}, {foo, 36}, {baz, 90}};
```

[`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GroupBy.html) (introduced in version 10) offers a concise syntax:

```
res = GroupBy[dat2, First -> Last, Total]
```

> ```
> <|baz -> 147, foo -> 123, bar -> 203|>
> ```

Note that this provides the flexibility of specifying `First` and `Last` as the functions that yield the parts to compare and combine.  For the specific format shown a shorter v10 method is to convert the expressions into a `Rule` list and [`Merge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Merge.html) them:

```
Merge[Rule @@@ dat2, Total]
```

> ```
> <|baz -> 147, foo -> 123, bar -> 203|>
> ```

The result is an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Association.html).  Keeping the data in this format has a number of benefits but it can also be converted back to a common `List` with [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) or [`KeyValueMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValueMap.html):

```
List @@@ Normal[res]

KeyValueMap[List, res]
```

> ```
> {{baz, 147}, {foo, 123}, {bar, 203}}
>
> {{baz, 147}, {foo, 123}, {bar, 203}}
> ```

Comment: From *Mathematica* version 10.1, `KeyValueMap` can be used on the association: `KeyValueMap[List, GroupBy[dat2, First -> Last, Total]]` or `KeyValueMap[List, Merge[Rule @@@ dat2, Total]]`.

Comment: @Xavier Thanks for the note.  I overlooked this comment before.

Answer (score 5):

This solution doesn't involve pattern matching and should be fast for large lists (pattern matching, especially with `___` slows down tremendously):

```
Block[{g},
    g[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}] := {x, y};
    g[x_List, y__List] := {First@x, Total[{x, y}[[All, 2]]]};
    Apply[g, (GatherBy[#, First] & /@ data), {2}]
]
```

Comment: I wrote (completely independently) almost the exact same function (even used `g` as the dummy function!) in a more recent question that I didn't realise was a duplicate of this one. I even got downvoted and annoyed cause I thought it was a decent answer! Naturally I will give you +1. I had defined `g[x_?VectorQ] := x;` in place of your `g[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}] := {x, y};` but I doubt this makes any difference here.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a straightforward one using replacements:

```
data /. {h___, {x_, y_}, b___, {x_, z_}, t___} :> {h, {x, y + z}, b, t}
(* Out[1]= {{{3542313600, 175}, {3542918400, 175}}, 
    {{3544128000, 450}, {3544732800, 450}, {3545337600, 900}, {3545942400, 450}, 
     {3546547200, 450}, {3547152000, 0}}} *)
```

Change the `/.` or `ReplaceAll` to `//.` or `ReplaceRepeated` for lists with multiple repeated first elements. This method doesn't sort the list.