# List-operations only when restrictions are fulfilled (Part 2)

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following:

```
data={{{3544128000, 80}, {3544732800, 80}, {3545337600, 80},
{3545942400, 80}, {3545942400, 160}, {3546547200, 160}, {3547152000, 0}}};
```

After the satisfying answers to my former question [(Part 1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4332/list-operations-only-when-restrictions-are-fulfilled-part-1), another issue occurred, but with the same background (List-operations only when restrictions are fulfilled):

After applying

```
Transpose[{#[[All, 1, 1]], 
      Total[#[[All, All, 2]], {2}]}] &[#] & /@ (GatherBy[#, First] & /@
    data)
```

on `data` (thanks to Andy Ross for the approach), I receive

```
{{{3544128000, 80}, {3544732800, 80}, {3545337600, 80}, {3545942400, 240},
{3546547200, 160}, {3547152000, 0}}}
```

which resembles to

```
{{x_-n*604800_, y_},...,{x_-604800_, y_}, {x_, u_},
{x+604800_, z_},{x_+2*604800_, z_},...,{x_+m*604800_, z_}}
```

I would like to do the following:

1. `u_->y_` (*Transform u_ to y_*)
2. `residual=(y_-u_)/(n+1)` (*Calculate residual of y_ and u_ and divide it be `n+1`*)
3. `{{x-n*604800_, y_+residual},...,{x-604800_, y_+residual}, {x_, y_+residual},{x+604800_, z_},{x_+2*604800_, z_},...,{x_+m*604800_, z_}}` (*Distribute `residual` to all periods from `x_-n*604800` to `x_`*)

The result in case of `data` will then be:

```
{{{3544128000, 120}, {3544732800, 120}, {3545337600, 120}, {3545942400, 120},
    {3546547200, 160}, {3547152000, 0}}}
```

For better understanding, please consider the following examples:

```
Example1 = {5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4};
MyFunction@Example1
{5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4}

Example2 = {2, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4};
MyFunction@Example2
{3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4}

Example3 = {2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4};
MyFunction@Example3
{2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4}
```

`MyFunction` detects a peak within the dataset and "kills" it by replacing the peak and the preceding sequence (with constant values) with `y+residual` (see `2.`, `Example1` and `Example2`). It is important that `MyFunction` returns the original list when no peak occurs in the list (see Example 3.).

Comment: I thought about something like
`ModifiedData /. {{a_, y_}, {x_, u_}, {b_, z_}} :> {{a, y + (u - y)/2}, {x, y + (u - y)/2}, {b, z}}` but would prefer a generic approach as this only works when `data` is modified to `ModifiedData`.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a transformation function according to

```
transform[list_] := Module[{n, y, u, res},
  y = list[[1, 2]];
  n = LengthWhile[list, #[[2]] == y&];
  u = list[[n + 1, 2]];
  res = (y - u)/n;
  Join[Thread[{list[[;; n + 1, 1]], y + res}], list[[n + 2 ;;]]]]
```

and map that to you transformed data list:

```
data = {{{3544128000, 80}, {3544732800, 80}, {3545337600, 80}, {3545942400, 80}, 
  {3545942400, 160}, {3546547200, 160}, {3547152000, 0}}};
data1 = Transpose[{#[[All, 1, 1]], Total[#[[All, All, 2]], {2}]}] & /@ 
  (GatherBy[#, First] & /@ data);

transform /@ data1
```

> ```
> {{{3544128000, 80/3}, {3544732800, 80/3}, {3545337600, 80/3}, 
>   {3545942400, 80/3}, {3546547200, 160}, {3547152000, 0}}}
> ```

By the way, I get

```
data1 == {{{3544128000, 80}, {3544732800, 80}, {3545337600, 80}, {3545942400, 240}, 
  {3546547200, 160}, {3547152000, 0}}}
```

instead of

```
{{{3544128000, 80}, {3544732800, 80}, {3545337600, 80}, {3545942400, 240},{3546547200, 160}}}
```

as posted in the question which is why I get an extra term `{3547152000, 0}` in the result above.

Comment: @John What are your comments? I can't see them.

Comment: Two comments on your approach:
1. `res` must be changed to `res=(u-y)/(n+1)`.
2. It is important that the function only runs in case of `{{x_-n*604800_, y_},...,{x_-604800_, y_}, {x_, u_},
{x+604800_, z_},{x_+2*604800_, z_},...,{x_+m*604800_, z_}}`, whereas `y<u<z`. In case of `y<u=z` the function must return the original list. Please consider the added information at the end of my question.

Comment: May be there is a way to use a pattern such as `{q___,x___,y___,z___,w___}`. `y` represents the peak and `q`,`x`,`z` and `w` represent sequences with constant values, whereas `x<y<z` (`q` and `w` can be of any other constant value).