# Leveling peaks in list

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following:

```
data={2,2,2,5,3,3,3,6,1,1,1,0};
In[1]:=result=MyFunction@data
Out[1]:={2,2,3.5,3.5,3,3,4.5,4.5,1,1,1,0}
```

`data[[{4,8}]]` represent the peaks which I want to level via `MyFunction` as follows:

```
{a___,PrePeakValue1_,peak1_,b___,PrePeakValue2_,peak2_,c___}:>{a,Mean1,Mean1,b,Mean2,Mean2,c}
```

whereas `Mean1=Mean@{PrePeakValue1,peak1}` (i.e. `Mean@{2,5}`) and `Mean2=Mean@{PrePeakValue2,peak2}` (i.e. `Mean@{3,6}`).

I posted this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4379/list-operations-only-when-restrictions-are-fulfilled-part-2)  already some time ago, but Heike's approach has one disadvantage: neither it identifies and therefor nor levels the second peak. I think using `LengthWhile` migth be one reason why it won't work.

EDIT:
`data` is just an example. I have other lists which may contain no, one or more than two peaks.

Comment: what is your desired output for the list `{2, 2, 2, 5, 4, 3, 3, 6, 5, 1, 1, 0}`? Is it `{2, 2, 3.5, 3.5, 4, 3, 4.5, 4.5, 5, 1, 1, 0}` or `{2., 2., 3.5, 3.75, 3.75, 3., 4.5, 4.75, 4.75, 1., 1., 0.}`?

Comment: ... a simpler example: what should the function give for input `{4, 10, 9, 8}`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
data={2,2,2,5,3,3,3,6,1,1,1,0};
data //. {a__, b_, c_, d_, e__} /; b < c > d :> {a, Mean[{b, c}],  Mean[{b, c}], d, e}

(*
-> {2, 2, 7/2, 7/2, 3, 3, 9/2, 9/2, 1, 1, 1, 0}
*)
```

Test drive

```
data = {2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 0};
ListLinePlot[{data, 
  data //. {a__, b_, c_, d_, e__} /; b < c > d :> {a, Mean[{b, c}], Mean[{b, c}], d, e}}
```

[image]

**Edit**

Answering John's comment. This works:

```
data = {575, 1242, 667, 667, 500, 500, 500, 500};
data //. {a___, b_, c_, d_, e___} /; b < c > d :> {a, Mean[{b, c}], Mean[{b, c}], d, e}
(*
-> {1817/2, 1817/2, 667, 667, 500, 500, 500, 500}
*)
```

I just changed `a__` for `a___` and `e__` for `e___` , allowing both ends to be null.

Comment: Thanks. Like my suggestion your approach is limited to two peaks. I would like Mathematica identify the number of peaks on its own.

Comment: @John Please post all your requirements on your question

Comment: @John Please see edit

Comment: A problem occurred with your approach. Consider the following:
`data = {575, 1242, 667, 667, 500, 500, 500, 500};`

Since `a___` does not exist, the code does not work.

Comment: @belisatius: I changed to mef's approach, as it does not show the problem which I described in my preceding comment. However, I prefer the way you tried to solve my problem. Maybe there is a way to customise your code, so that it works for any data?

Comment: @John See edit please

Comment: @John NEVER accept a procedural approach as the better one in Mma. A functional or pattern matching style should always be better in performance (see LS's answer) or simplicity

Comment: Only for completeness: I changed something in my code, which led to another layout of `data`:
`dataNew=Transpose[{Range[Length@data],data}]`. I agree with belisarius, that his approach is the most simple/comprehensible one. Applying his approach on `dataNew` therefor is easy: `dataNew //. {a___, {x_,b_}, {y_,c_}, {z_,d_}, e___} /; b < c > d :> {a, {x,Mean[{b, c}]}, {y,Mean[{b, c}]}, {z,d}, e}`

Comment: I just discovered that there is one problem with your approach. Lets say you have `data={10,0,0,0,10}`. Then both, the first and the last value, are extrem values which I would like to level as described. I did not pay attention to this case when I asked my question. The problem I see, is that the approach must extend `data` to the left. (desired result: `res={5,5,0,0,5,5}`. Note: `Length@res-Length@data=1`)

Comment: @John But ... what is the condition for an endpoint to be considered a "peak"? Are you comparing it with its only neighbor?

Comment: An extreme value is always to be levelled if its neighbour is lower (e.g. `dataNoLevelling={1,5,5,5,1}` -> `(*resNoLevelling={1,5,5,5,1}*)`and `dataLevelling={100,5,5,5,100}` -> `(*resLevelling={50,50,5,5,52.5,52,5}*)`

Comment: The following works but maybe there is a better approach: `first = {left_, right_, rest___} /; left > right :> {left/2, left/2, 
    right, rest};`
`sec = {rest___, left_, right_} /; right > left :> {rest, 
    Mean[{left, right}], Mean[{left, right}]};`
`third = {a___, b_, c_, d_, e___} /; b < c > d :> {a, Mean[{b, c}], 
    Mean[{b, c}], d, e};`

`(# //. first //. sec //. third) & @ data`

Comment: @John `(Join[{data[[2]]}, data, {data[[-2]]}] //. {a__, b_, c_, d_, e__} /; b < c > d :> {a,  Mean[{b, c}], Mean[{b, c}], d, e})[[2 ;; -2]]` ?

Comment: Almost. With `{a___, b_, c_, d_, e___}` instead of `{a__, b_, c_, d_, e__}` it works. (i.e. `BlankNullSequence` instead of `BlankSequence`)

Answer (score 8):

This is reasonably performant, but top-level:

```
Clear[ff,toLinkedList];
toLinkedList[l_List] := Fold[{#2, #1} &, {}, Reverse@l];

ff[data_] := ff[{}, toLinkedList@data];
ff[accum_List, {x_, {y_, rest : {z_, _}}} /; y > x && y > z] :=
    ff[{accum, {#, #} &[N@Mean[{x, y}]]}, rest];
ff[accum_List, {x_, rest_}] := ff[{accum, x}, rest];
ff[accum_List, {}] := Flatten[accum];
```

The usage is

```
ff[data]
```

This is rather ugly, but several times faster:

```
Clear[peakPositions];
peakPositions[data_] :=
   Position[
      First@Differences[
         Clip[Differences@Partition[data, Length[data] - 2, 1], {-1, 1}]], 
      -2] + 1;

Clear[myFunction];
myFunction[data_] :=
   Module[{d = data, pos},
     pos = Flatten@Transpose[{# - 1, #}] &@peakPositions[data];
     d[[pos]] = N@Flatten@Transpose[{#, #}] &@Total[Partition[d[[pos]], 2], {2}]/2;
     d]
```

The usage is

```
myFunction[data]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a procedural version:

```
trimPeaks[data_] :=
 Module[{d = data},
  Do[
   If[
    d[[i - 1]] < d[[i]] > d[[i + 1]],
    d[[{i - 1, i}]] = Mean[d[[{i - 1, i}]]]
    ],
   {i, 2, Length[d] - 1}];
  d
  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[localmaxpos, leveledpeaks];
localmaxpos[list_List] := Pick[Range@Length@list, 
   (Prepend[#, 0] - Append[#, 0]) &@(Sign@Differences@list), 2];
leveledpeaks[dt_List] :=  Module[{list = dt, pos = localmaxpos[dt]}, 
 (list[[# - 1 ;; # ]] = {Mean[list[[# - 1 ;; #]]], Mean[list[[# - 1 ;; #]]]}) & /@ pos; list];    
data = {2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 0};
leveledpeaks[data]
(* ==> {2, 2, 7/2, 7/2, 3, 3, 9/2, 9/2, 1, 1, 1, 0}*)
leveledpeaks[{2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 0}]
(* ==> {2, 2, 7/2, 7/2, 3, 3, 9/2, 9/2, 1, 1, 1, 0} *)
```

As J.M. noted in the comments, the selector array inside `Pick[...]`

```
(Prepend[#, 0] - Append[#, 0]) &@(Sign@Differences@list)
```

can be replaced with

```
ListCorrelate[{1, -1}, #, {-1, 1}, 0] &@(Sign@ListCorrelate[{-1, 1}, list])
```

or with

```
ListConvolve[{-1, 1}, #, {1, -1}, 0] &@(Sign@ListConvolve[{1, -1}, list])
```

Comment: The `(Prepend[#, 0] - Append[#, 0]) &` can be replaced with `ListCorrelate[{1, -1}, #, {-1, 1}, 0] &`, among other things...

Comment: @J.M. good point! Thanks!

Comment: As it stands, your current implementation of `leveledpeaks[]` chokes when given an explicit list; e.g. `leveledpeaks[{2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 0}]`. It's easily fixed, though: `leveledpeaks[da_] := Module[{data = da}, (data[[# - 1 ;; # + 1]] = Append[ConstantArray[Mean[data[[# - 1 ;; #]]], 2], data[[# + 1]]]) & /@ localmaxpos[data];
   data];`

Comment: Thank you again, @J.M.! Just added the fix  and alternative specs for the selector array inside `Pick` that you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Using `SequenceReplace` (new in 11.3)

```
list = {2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 0};

SequenceReplace[list, {a_, b_, c_} /; a < b > c :> 
  Sequence[(a + b)/2, (a + b)/2, c]]
```

{2, 2, 7/2, 7/2, 3, 3, 9/2, 9/2, 1, 1, 1, 0}

Answer (score 1):

Using `ReplacePart`, `SequencePosition` and `SequenceCases`:

```
list = {2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 0};

pos[l_List] := Map[List /@ Extract[Map[Range @@ # &, 
               SequencePosition[l, {a_, b_, c_} /; a < b > c]], 
               {All, #}] &, Range[2]]

patt[l_List] := Array[SequenceCases[#, {a_, b_, c_} /; a < b > c :> Mean[{a, b}]]
                &@l &, Length[pos[l]]]

reparray[l_List] := {pos[l], patt[l]};

rep[l_List] := Catenate@MapThread[Thread@Rule[#1, #2] &, reparray[l]]

ReplacePart[#, rep[#]] &@list

(*{2, 2, 7/2, 7/2, 3, 3, 9/2, 9/2, 1, 1, 1, 0}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a procedural version following @mef's idea, but using `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
 trimPeaks[data_] := Module[{l = data},
    Part[
            Reap[
                Do[
                    If[
                        Inequality[Part[l, i - 1],
                                Less,
                                l[[i]],
                                Greater,
                                Part[l, i + 1]
                            ],
                        Sow[Mean[{Part[l, i - 1], l[[i]]}]];
                        Part[l, {i - 1, i}] = Mean[{Part[l, i - 1], l[[i]]}];
                    ],
                    {i, 2, Length[l] - 1}
                ]
            ],
            2, 1
        ];
    l
   ];

trimPeaks[list]

(*{2, 2, 7/2, 7/2, 3, 3, 9/2, 9/2, 1, 1, 1, 0}*)
```