# Local max/min of Mathematica data sets

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a way in Mathematica to find the local maxima of a set of points?

Suppose you have

```
points={{xa,ya},{xb,yb},{xc,yc}...}

peakQ[{{x1_,y1_},{x2_,y2_},{x3_,y3_}}] := Abs[y1] > Abs[y2] && Abs[y2] < Abs[y3];
peaks=Map[#[[2]]&, Select[Partition[points,3,1],peakQ[#]&]]
```

Is it correct because in this way I find points but from plots I can see that I have lost some points.

Comment: Could you make a concrete, numerical example to help clarify ?

Comment: I feel your use of `Abs` is incorrect. Is there a reason to include them?

Comment: You could start by modifying the solutions in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5759)...

Answer (score 15):

Here s another version to do it. First: some data

```
points = SortBy[RandomReal[1, {50, 2}], First]
```

This gives you the positions of the maxima and minima:

```
maxima = 1 + Position[Differences[Sign[Differences[points[[All, 2]]]]], -2]
minima = 1 + Position[Differences[Sign[Differences[points[[All, 2]]]]], 2]

peaks = Extract[points,maxima]
```

which you can see by plotting them:

```
ListLinePlot[points, Prolog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[Extract[points, maxima]], Green, Point[Extract[points, minima]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### How it works:

- `points[[All,2]]` only takes the y-values
- `Sign[Differences[...]]` takes the consecutive difference, and their Sign (i.e. -1, 0, or 1)
- You are looking for something that goes up (+1) and down again (-1). So, we take `Differences[...]` again, and then look where the result is -2 (for maxima), or, equivalently, 2 (for minima). That is done with `Position[...,2]`.
- We have to add 1 because taking `Differences` makes the lists shorter
- `Extract[points,maxima]` then gives you your results

### And yet another version:

```
peaks = Pick[points[[2 ;; -2]], Differences[Sign[Differences[points[[All, 2]]]]], -2]
```

...with the same rationale as above, but using the functionality of `Pick`. One needs to drop the first and the last entry of `points` so that it has the same length as the other list.

### Timing comparisons:

```
points = SortBy[RandomReal[1, {10^6, 2}], First];

peakQ[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, {x3_, y3_}}] := y1 < y2 && y2 > y3
Timing[peaks1 = Select[Partition[points, 3, 1], peakQ][[All, 2]];]
(* 4 sec *)
Timing[peaks2 = Extract[points, 1 + Position[Differences[Sign[Differences[points[[All, 2]]]]], -2]];]
(* 0.4 sec *)
Timing[peaks3 = Pick[points[[2 ;; -2]], Differences[Sign[Differences[points[[All, 2]]]]], -2];]
(* 0.1 sec *)

peaks1 == peaks2 == peaks3
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do a search for extrema (differential calculus), on the interpolated version of your dataset. See how to get an interpolated function from a set of data points [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10986/89). The simplest way (assuming you have polynomial data) is to do a polynomial fit over `points`:

```
points = {
 {-5., 365.}, {-4.951, 356.571}, {-4.804, 331.998}, {-1.888, 38.604},
 {-0.018, -0.033}, {2.565, 54.056}, {3.285, 79.016}, {6.3, 159.451},
 {6.459, 160.646}, {6.715, 161.555}, {6.839, 161.524}, {7.06, 160.659},
 {8.971, 100.783}, {10.901, -85.324}, {15., -1095.}
 }; (* points sampled from -x^3 + 10 x^2 + 2 x *)

fit = Fit[points, {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x];
f = Function[{x}, Evaluate@fit]

f[x]
```

> ```
> 0.00401351 + 2.00137 x + 9.99945 x^2 - 0.999973 x^3
> ```

Afterwards, you can get the derivative of your curve, `f`. The function `f` is our fitted polynomial function:

```
Plot[{f[x], f'[x], f''[x]}, {x, -5, 15}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where the first derivative is zero the function has a stationary point:

```
sol = NSolve[{f'[x] == 0}, x, Reals]
```

> `{{x -> -0.0986535}, {x -> 6.76506}}`

Checking the second derivative tells whether at the given point of interest `f` has a minimum or maximum (or `f[x]` is an inflection point):

```
f''[x] /. sol
```

> `{20.5912, -20.5912}`

where:

- $f^{\prime\prime}(x) < 0$ -> $f$ has a local maximum at $x$.
- $f^{\prime\prime}(x) > 0$ -> $f$ has a local minimum at $x$.
- $f^{\prime\prime}(x) = 0$ -> $f$ has an inflection point at $x$

Thus:

```
minmax = MapThread[# -> 
   Which[#2 < 0, "max", #2 > 0, "min", True, "inflection"] &, {x /. 
   sol, f''[x] /. sol}]
```

> `{-0.0986535 -> "min", 6.76506 -> "max"}`

```
Plot[{f[x], f'[x]}, {x, -5, 15}, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize@5, Red, 
   Point[{#, f[#]} & /@ (x /. sol)], Black, 
   Text[Last@#, {First@#, f@First@#}, {-1, 1}] & /@ minmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

In versions 10+, you can use [FindPeaks](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPeaks.html):

```
SeedRandom[123]
points = SortBy[RandomReal[1, {40, 2}], First];

xvalues = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> #[[1]] &, points, 1];
peaks = {# /. xvalues, #2} & @@@ FindPeaks[points[[All, 2]], 0, 0, -Infinity];
valleys = {# /. xvalues, -#2} & @@@ FindPeaks[-points[[All, 2]], 0, 0, -Infinity];

ListPlot[{points, peaks, valleys}, Joined -> {True, False, False}, 
  BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution based on code from **giacomo**'s question, assuming that `points` have distinct $x$-coordinates.

```
In[1]:= points=SortBy[RandomReal[1,{10,2}],First]
Out[1]= {{0.0120925,0.643074},{0.180014,0.667626},{0.250923,0.696545},{0.332885,0.0217103},{0.374107,0.13732},{0.444013,0.0420624},{0.45527,0.706021},{0.547433,0.454037},{0.852822,0.897056},{0.903773,0.112657}}
```

As **Sjoerd** pointed out, we do not need to use `Abs`.  I think you need to switch the inequalities if you want the local maximum points.

```
In[2]:= peakQ[{{x1_,y1_},{x2_,y2_},{x3_,y3_}}]:=y1<y2 && y2>y3
```

We can simply use `peakQ` as opposed to `peakQ[#]&` in `Select`.

```
In[3]:= peaks=Select[Partition[points,3,1],peakQ][[All,2]]
Out[3]= {{0.250923,0.696545},{0.374107,0.13732},{0.45527,0.706021},{0.852822,0.897056}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`FindPeaks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPeaks.html) or [`PeakDetect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PeakDetect.html).  The parameters of each of these can be adjusted for peak selection sensitivity.  Below I show with default sensitivity.

### `FindPeaks` for `TimeSeries` data

First generate some data in a `TimeSeries`.

```
SeedRandom[87];
rp = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, 100, 1}];
```

The with `FindPeaks`

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[rp],
 ListPlot[FindPeaks[rp]["Path"], PlotStyle -> Green],
 ListPlot[(-FindPeaks[-rp])["Path"], PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### `PeakDetect` for `List` data

```
data = rp["Path"];
```

Then

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[rp],
 ListPlot[Pick[data, PeakDetect[data[[All, 2]]], 1], PlotStyle -> Green],
 ListPlot[Pick[data, PeakDetect[-data[[All, 2]]], 1], PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see both methods select the same locations with default settings and the both have the same parameters available for adjusting selection sensitivity.

Hope this helps.