# Determining the local extrema of discrete data

Tags: mathematical-optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Local max/min of Mathematica data sets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13557/local-max-min-of-mathematica-data-sets)

If I have a continuous function `f` (for example `f = Sin[x]`), I can find the local extrema in the vicinity of $x = x_0$ using `FindMinimum[f, {x, x0}]` and `FindMaximum[f, {x, x0}]`.  For example:

```
FindMinimum[Sin[x], {x, Pi}]
FindMaximum[Sin[x], {x, Pi}]

(* {-1., {x -> 4.71239}} *)
(* {1., {x -> 1.5708}} *)
```

However, what if I have a discrete function -- a function described by a list of points?  This comes up frequently when working with data from experiments.  For example, suppose I have the following discrete function described by `x` and `f`:

```
x = Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.1];
f = Sin[x];
Show[{
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All],
  ListPlot[Transpose[{x, f}]]
```

[image: Sine function]

How can I find the local extrema of the data defined by `Transpose[{x, f}]`?

I could interpolate the data and then use `FindMinimum` and `FindMaximum`:

```
interp = Interpolation[Transpose[{x, f}]]
FindMinimum[interp[x], {x, Pi}]
FindMaximum[interp[x], {x, Pi}]

(* InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 6.2}}, <>] *)

(* {-0.999999, {{0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1., 
    1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2., 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 
    2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3., 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 
    3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4., 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 
    5., 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 6., 6.1, 6.2} -> 
   4.71232}} *)

(* {0.999998, {{0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1., 1.1,
     1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2., 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 
    2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3., 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 
    3.8, 3.9, 4., 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5., 
    5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 6., 6.1, 6.2} -> 
   1.57084}} *)
```

But is there any way to find the local extrema without using `Interpolation`?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: You could use `Differences[f]` and locate where they change sign.

Comment: It depends on your data, but you can use also `Min`and `Max`.

Comment: a related question (for reference) http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5575/how-to-find-all-the-local-minima-maxima-in-a-range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps a combination of `ListConvolve` and `Nearest` would work.  This allows you to create a sort of moving `Map` of any function you want including `Min` and `Max`.

```
movingMap[fn_, data_, w_] := 
 Nearest[Rule @@@ 
   Transpose[{Median /@ Partition[data[[All, 1]], w, 1], 
     ListConvolve[ConstantArray[1, w], data[[All, 2]], {-1, 1}, {}, 
      Times, fn[{##}] &]}]]
```

Here it is with `Min` and `Max`using a window width of 3.

```
Plot[{movingMap[Max, data, 3][t], movingMap[Min, data, 3][t]}, {t, 0, 
  6}, PlotPoints -> 250]
```

[image]

You can use more exotic functions.  Here I'm using the .975 and .025 quantiles to get a 95% confidence estimate this time with a window width of 6.

```
Plot[{movingMap[Quantile[#, .975] &, data, 6][t], 
  movingMap[Quantile[#, .025] &, data, 6][t]}, {t, 0, 6}, 
 PlotPoints -> 250]
```

[image]

Note that I'm using `Median` on the moving `Partition` as locations in `Nearest` you may want to adjust this to be the first element of the window or some other number.

Answer (score 3):

With some data:

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}]
```

You could partition it into triplets, then pick out which ones have the higher middle point:

```
Cases[Partition[data, 3, 1], {{_, a_}, p : {_, b_}, {_, c_}} /; a < b && c < b -> p]
```

> `{{1.6, 0.999574}}`

You can easily adjust the condition to pick out minima.

Be warned though, that this does only what it says: pick out a point from your data that is strictly higher that its neighbours.  It's not going to work with plateaux.  And with experimental data, you might have to deal with noise and error which could give you hundreds of local maxima.

Answer (score 2):

If your coordinates are the set of points $\{x,f\}$, then run a three-point median filter`m=MedianFilter[f,1]` and compare function values $f$ to filtered values $m$. The function $f$ has a local maximum at a point where $f>m$. A local minimum occurs where $f<m$. On slopes, the median equals the function value. Pick locations where the function value and its median are unequal, these are the extrema.

Comment: This only works for monotonic functions, not plateaux. For example, [2, 1, 1] has $f = m$ but I would consider f a minimum.

Comment: Assume `f={2,1,1}`. Then `m=MedianFilter[f,1]={3/2,1,1}`. The function value 2 is greater than the filtered value 3/2, so there is a local maximum at the first position, that is at `f=2`. There is no local minimum because no value of `f` is less than the corresponding value of `m`.