# Numerically finding a derivative jump of a function

Tags: functions, numerics

How would I numerically find where a function has derivative jumps?

In particular, I'm working with this function:

```
f[k_?IntegerQ,y_?NumberQ] := 
   x /. FindRoot[Nest[y/4 Sin[\[Pi] #] &, x, k] == x, {x, 1}]
```

[image: k=1] [image: k=2]

Comment: You can use Ctrl+D and the GetCoordinate from the Drawing Tools.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I ask for a general method.

Comment: A suggestion: you could try using `GradientFilter[]` on a sampling of your data, and then use the methods [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13557) to pick out extrema, whose locations should hopefully correspond to where your jump discontinuities are...

Comment: @swish : You might this concept useful : http://mathoverflow.net/q/165038/14414

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function is not to wild `Interpolation` could be of use:

```
t = Table[{x, f[2, x]}, {x, 0, 4, 1/10000.}];
it = Interpolation[t]
```

Large values of second derivatives are probably caused by discontinuities in the first derivative:

```
discontinuities = Reap[Do[If[Abs[it''[x]] > 2000, Sow[{x, it[x]}]], {x, 0, 4, 1/1000.}]][[2, 1]]

ListLinePlot[t, Epilog -> {Red, Point@discontinuities}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

BTW You may have trouble with this function. Take for instance `f[3,x]`:

```
Plot[f[3, x], {x, 0, 4}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I will try it now, I just need to know where the jumps are so I can include a better intervals for finding roots in the definition of a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can maximize the derivative :

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{0, x < 2}, {Sqrt[x - 2], x >= 2}}];

NMaximize[Abs[f'[x]], x]

(* {1.84154*10^6, {x -> 2.}} *)
```

Comment: Function is numerical, so we need a numerical derivative, and there could be multiple jumps, I would want to find them all.

Comment: @swish You can calculate the numerical derivative and find all its maxima. Then you're dealing with finding all the local maxima of a function (which is hard in general).

Comment: The equation defining your `f` has (possibly) multiple solutions other than `x=0`, which you can get using [RootSearch](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/).