# Finding all the local minima from a noisy data plot

Tags: list-manipulation, histograms, maximum

I have a data with noisy data which has lot of minimas. One such data file is shown [here](http://pastebin.com/0yH38AZz). What I have been trying to do is the following,

(1) I would  to find all the minimas with respect to the common reference bar.

(2) then I have to find the distance between those minimas

(3) and make a histogram.

(2) ,(3) can be done if I could identify all the minimas. I tried couple of methods ,but did not get work here.

[image]

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5575/how-to-find-all-the-local-minima-maxima-in-a-range), [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23828/finding-local-minima-maxima-in-noisy-data), and `FindPeaks` and `PeakDetect` might be helpful.

Comment: This question is basically a duplicate of ["Finding Local Minima / Maxima in Noisy Data"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23828/34008), so I vote to close. For example, see [the results over the question data](http://i.imgur.com/YEfpIe9.png) of [my solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95618/34008) in the referenced discussion.

Comment: Mr Anton, Did you put a reference bar or something, You see I only want minima w.r.t reference bar not everything

Comment: @TM90 You have not defined the bar in the question. If you do, selecting the local extrema outside of it is trivial.

Comment: yeah sure, I guess that will do. Thanks Mr Anton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
minima = TakeSmallestBy[#[[2]] &, 1] /@
         Split[
             Pick[data, MinDetect[data[[All, 2]], 0.001], 1],
             #1[[1]] + 0.002 == #2[[1]] &
         ]
ListPlot[minima, PlotRange -> All]
Differences@Flatten[minima, 1][[All, 1]]
```

I used the threshold 0.001 to define the "reference bar." I also used the fact that the x-values in the data set were all exactly 0.002 apart to separate distinct minima.

`MinDetect` forms the basis of this approach. The rest is just list manipulation to isolate the minima and the associated x-values for finding distances.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Josh Bishop, it does work.

Comment: Good solution. (+1)