# Total elements of a list that have a common first element

Tags: list-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List-operations only when restrictions are fulfilled (Part 1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4332/list-operations-only-when-restrictions-are-fulfilled-part-1)

I have a set of data like:

```
list = {{Tim, 45},{Mary,100},{Tim,500},{Bob,499},{Mary,50}};
```

I'm looking for a simple way to total the values based off of the name so that the output would look like: `{{Tim,545},{Mary,150},{Bob,499}}`

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate (can't find it right now), but a simple way would be to use `GatherBy[..., First] //. {h___, {a_, b_}, {a_, c_}, t___} :> {h, {a, b + c}, t}` (you might need to flatten appropriately at the end)

Comment: Gather didn't work...but GatherBy worked just fine . Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, I meant `GatherBy` :) I typed quickly off the top of my head and didn't run it in mma. Fixed it now

Comment: @rm-rf is this it? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4332/121  Well, I cannot see how it is *not* a duplicate so **closed as duplicate**.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, that's the one I was thinking about (this one has the better title though)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do this in one go:

```
Reap[Sow @@@ Reverse[list, {2}], _, {#1, Total[#2]} &][[2]]
```

Comment: Wow that's awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

another way

```
expr = {{"Tim", 45}, {"Mary", 100}, {"Tim", 500}, {"Bob", 499}, {"Mary", 50}}

b = Gather[expr, First[#1] == First[#2] &]
{First[# [[All,1]] ], Total[# [[All, 2]] ]} & /@ b
```

gives

```
{{Tim,545},{Mary,150},{Bob,499}}
```