# How to sum over duplicates?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have a list of the form:

```
{{1, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 3}, {2, 4, 2}, {2, 1, -1}, {1, 0 ,0}}
```

that I would like to sort such that I calculate the sum over the third column whenever the first two columns are equal.  I.e. in this case the output would be

```
{{1, 0, 1 + 3 + 0}, {2, 1, 2 + (-1)}, {2, 4, 2}}
```

or

```
 {{1, 0, 4},{2, 1, 1},{2, 4, 2}}
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4332/5 Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16115/5

Comment: @rm-rf Looking at your first link the principle is the same. However gathering based on **both** first and second columns, as opposed to just the first, is probably not obvious to a new user. Keeping the first 2 columns together also means that you have to wrap `Flatten` around the mapped function.

Comment: See also: [(17734)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17734/121)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Flatten[{#[[1, {1, 2}]], Total[#[[All, 3]]]}] & /@ GatherBy[yourList, #[[{1, 2}]] &]

(*  {{1, 0, 4}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 4, 2}} *)
```

How this works:

```
GatherBy[yourList, #[[{1, 2}]] &]
```

this gathers elements of your list based on matching the first and second elements in each sub-list (`#[[{1, 2}]] &`)

Once common elements are gathered (collected) you can total/sum all the third elements by mapping them onto `Total`

Comment: Perfect!  I was unaware of the GatherBy function and, yes, using it with more than one column was not obvious to this new user.

Answer (score 5):

```
 lists = {{1, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 3}, {2, 4, 2}, {2, 1, -1}, {1, 0, 0}}
```

**`Reap/Sow`:**

```
 Reap[Sow[#[[3]], {#[[{1, 2}]]}] & /@ lists, _,  Append[#1, Total@#2] &][[2]]
```

**`ReplaceRepeated`:**

```
 lists //. {a___, {x_, y_, z_}, b___, {x_, y_, w_}, c___} :> {a, {x, y, z + w}, b, c}
```

**`Cases` + `DeleteDuplicates`:**

```
 DeleteDuplicates@Cases[lists, {w : PatternSequence[_, _], _} :>
         {w, Total@(Last /@ Cases[lists, {w, _}])}]
```

all give

> {{1, 0, 4}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 4, 2}}

**Update:** In versions 10+, you can also use `Merge`:

```
KeyValueMap[Append]@Merge[Tr][Most @ # -> Last @ #& /@ lists]
```

> {{1, 0, 4}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 4, 2}}

Comment: +1 for the `ReplaceRepeated`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Total@#/PadLeft[{1}, 3, Length@#] & /@ GatherBy[list, #[[{1, 2}]] &]
```

This approach is basically the same as Mike's. However, instead of summing only the last element it sums all the elements. To correct for the extra summing `PadLeft[{1}, 3, Length@#]` is used to divide by the number of times it was added where the `{1}` is included to keep the last element the same. The approach can be generalized to lists of length $n$ by replacing `PadLeft[{1}, 3, Length@#]` with `PadLeft[{1}, Length@#[[1]], Length@#]`

Comment: You might give a bit of explanation as to what your code is doing and why it works.

Answer (score 2):

[`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html), introduced in *Mathemtaica 10*, is applicable here and cleaner than `GatherBy`:

```
in = {{1, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 3}, {2, 4, 2}, {2, 1, -1}, {1, 0, 0}};

Append @@@ Normal @ GroupBy[in, Most -> Last, Tr]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 4}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 4, 2}}
> ```

See also:

- [Combining values in one column (or part) when values in another column (or part) match](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4332/5)

Answer (score 1):

Since `GatherBy` and `Sow`/`Reap` are already shown I'll drop back to "first principles" as it were and use more basic language.

```
dat = {{1, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 3}, {2, 4, 2}, {2, 1, -1}, {1, 0, 0}};

f[dat_] :=
 Module[{key},
   key[__] = 0;
   key[#, #2] += #3 & @@@ dat;
   Most @ DownValues @ key /. (_@_@x__ :> y_) :> {x, y}
 ]

f @ dat
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 4}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 4, 2}}
> ```