# Combining two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I obtain an intersection of two or more list of lists conditioned on the first element of each sub-list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16450/how-do-i-obtain-an-intersection-of-two-or-more-list-of-lists-conditioned-on-the)

I would like to combine two lists.

```
list1 = {{134, 12}, {136, 14}, {140, 45}}
```

and

```
list2 = {{134, "B"}, {135, "A"}, {136, "E"}, {137, "A"}, {138,"I"}, {139, "B"}, {140, "G"}}
```

the result should be:

```
result = {{134, 12, "B"}, {136, 14, "E"}, {140, 45, "G"}}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is barely different from your previous question and those answers should provide you with the way to go with this one.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility (not optimized for speed, but readability) :

```
list1 /. {i_Integer, x_} :> 
       {i, x, i /. Apply[Rule, list2, {1}]}
```

Comment: Rolf that is far more concise than any of the answers to yesterdays question. You should post your answer there in case this question gets closed.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch o.k., did so, but had to add a MemberQ, so probably this is not that efficient. But I often trade efficiency for readability these days.

Comment: I prefer readability as well unless the speed differences are too large to be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

the answers to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16450/how-do-i-obtain-an-intersection-of-two-or-more-list-of-lists-conditioned-on-the/16452#16452) question will work for you. Just `Flatten` the final lists

```
processList[list1_, list2_] := 
 Module[{intersection, tmp1, tmp2},
  intersection = Intersection[list1[[All, 1]], list2[[All, 1]]];
  tmp1 = Cases[list1, {x_ /; MemberQ[intersection, x], __}];
  tmp2 = Cases[list2, {x_ /; MemberQ[intersection, x], __}];
  Flatten[{#[[1, 1]], ##[[All, 2]]}] & /@ 
   GatherBy[Join[tmp1, tmp2], First]
  ]

processList[list1, list2]
(* {{134, 12, "B"}, {136, 14, "E"}, {140, 45, "G"}}  *)
```

Comment: thank you for this solution. how could I adopt it if one or both lists would have more than one column which should be copied.

Comment: @Frink Your last question dealt specifically with matching more than one column. There is also this which might be a guide for your generic question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16507/how-to-sum-over-duplicates/16508#16508.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
Join[list1, List /@ Last /@ Select[list2, MemberQ[First /@ list1, #[[1]]] &], 2]
```

> {{134, 12, "B"}, {136, 14, "E"}, {140, 45, "G"}}

Answer (score 2):

As Mike told there was a very well written answer to your previous question that may address this question too. I show another way using pattern replacement for this purpose.

First form this rule

```
rule=(# /. List -> Rule) & /@ list2
```

> {134 -> "B", 135 -> "A", 136 -> "E", 137 -> "A", 138 -> "I", 139 -> "B", 140 -> "G"}

Now we take the first column of `list1` and apply the `rule`.

```
column3rd=list1[[All, 1]] /. rule
```

> {"B", "E", "G"}

Now form your expected list by joining the above list with the other two existing columns

```
(Transpose[list1]~Join~{column3rd}) // Transpose
```

> {{134, 12, "B"}, {136, 14, "E"}, {140, 45, "G"}}

BR