# Total by a criteria

Tags: list-manipulation, group-theory

I am developing a weighted KNN algorithm. In a step, I need to do the sum of  weights of each class. For example:

```
weightsPerclass = {{1, 0.2, .3, .4, .1, .3, .9, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5}};
```

Here the first row contains the weights and the second row contains the class labels.

I need to do the sum for each class and I return

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 5}, {2.6, .2, .6, 0}}
> ```

We can use a loop but I need a more compact solution. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many ways to do this.

```
w = {{1, 0.2, .3, .4, .1, .3, .9, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5}};
class = Union[w[[2]]];
Map[Total, Cases[Transpose[w], {x_, y_} /; y == # :> x] & /@ class];
{class, %}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: FYI: There is a performance problem with this approach.  The entire list must be rescanned for every element in `class` which will cause considerable slow-down as the length of that list increases.  This is the problem I was referring to in [(25591)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25591/121).

Answer (score 9):

Additional methods using `WeightedData`, `EmpiricalDistribution`, `GatherBy` and `SparseArray`:

```
{weights,classes} = weightsPerclass = {{1, 0.2, .3, .4, .1, .3, .9, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5}};
```

**WeightedData**

```
wd = WeightedData[classes, weights];
```

The property `"EmpiricalPDF"` *almost* gives what we need

```
wd["EmpiricalPDF"]
(* {{1,2,3,5},{0.8125,0.0625,0.125,0.}} *)
```

except that it has to be *de-normalized* by `Total[weights]`:

```
{First@# , Total[weights] Last@#} &@wd["EmpiricalPDF"]
(* {{1,2,3,5},{2.6,0.2,0.4,0.}} *)
```

Defining a function you can get the result in one step:

```
wdF = With[{p = WeightedData[#2, #1]["EmpiricalPDF"], w = Total @ #}, {1, w} p] &;

wdF[weights, classes]
(* {{1,2,3,5},{2.6,0.2,0.4,0.}} *)
```

**EmpiricalDistribution**

```
ed = EmpiricalDistribution[Rule @@ weightsPerclass];
ed["Domain"]
(* {1,2,3,5} *)

Total[weights] ed["Weights"]
(* {2.6,0.2,0.4,0.} *)

{%%, %}
(* {{1, 2, 3, 5}, {2.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0.}} *)
```

You can also define a function that returns the desired output in one step:

```
ClearAll[wedF]
wedF = With[{d = EmpiricalDistribution[# -> #2], w = Total@#}, {d["Domain"], w d["Weights"]}] &;

wedF[weights, classes]
(* {{1, 2, 3, 5}, {2.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0.}} *)
```

**GatherBy**

```
ClearAll[gthrBy];
gthrBy = Transpose[{Last@First@#, Total[First /@ #]} & /@ GatherBy[Transpose@#, Last]] &;

gthrBy@weightsPerclass
(* {{1,2,3,5},{2.6,0.2,0.4,0}} *)
```

**SparseArray**

```
System`SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" ->Total}];
sa = SparseArray[classes -> weights];
System`SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> First}];
{Flatten[sa["NonzeroPositions"]], sa["NonzeroValues"]}
(* {{1,2,3,5},{2.6,0.2,0.4,0}} *)
```

See also: [Optimizing 2D binning code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17742/125) and [Fast 2D binning algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8178714/884752)

**GroupBy - Version 10**

```
Through[{Keys,Values}[GroupBy[Transpose@weightsPerclass,Last -> First, Total]]]
 (* {{1,2,3,5}, {2.6,0.2,0.4,0}} *)
```

Comment: You're a madman.

Comment: @kguler, thanks

Comment: @kguler Why the empirical PDF does not give directly the best resuls. Why we have to multiply the results by the Total[weights]. Could you explain this point please?

Comment: @Developer2000, PDF values are normalized so that they add up to 1 over the domain; i.e. `pdf[i]` is `totalWeight [i] / totalWeight[j in Domain]`. To get the raw weights we need to multiply pdf values by the total weight of all values in the domain.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html) and [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html):

```
Transpose[
 Last@Reap[
   MapThread[Sow, weightsPerclass], _, {#1, Total@#2} &]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 5}, {2.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

If you have [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Association.html) functionality there is a rather nice approach using [`Merge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Merge.html):

```
w = {{1, 0.2, .3, .4, .1, .3, .9, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5}};

Thread[#2 -> # & @@ w] ~Merge~ Total
```

> ```
> <|1 -> 2.6, 2 -> 0.2, 3 -> 0.4, 5 -> 0|>
> ```

The output is itself an association.  It may be desirable to keep the format.  If not:

```
List @@@ Normal[%]\[Transpose]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 5}, {2.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0}}
> ```

If you cannot use associations it is better is to use [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GatherBy.html):

```
{#[[1, 2]], Tr @ #[[All, 1]]} & /@ GatherBy[w\[Transpose], Last]\[Transpose]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 5}, {2.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0}}
> ```

Unlike Nasser's code this does not rescan the list for every unique element in the second part which would result in considerable slow-down as that number increases.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but here's a way using `PositionIndex` (v10):

```
With[
 {pi = PositionIndex[weightsPerclass[[2]]]},
 {Keys@pi, Plus @@ (weightsPerclass[[1, #]]) & /@ Values@pi}
 ]
```

> `{{1, 2, 3, 5}, {2.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0}}`

Answer (score 2):

Step for step:

```
data = {{1, 0.2, .3, .4, .1, .3, .9, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5}};

mult = data[[1]] * data[[2]]
```

> {1, 0.4, 0.9, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.9, 0}

```
union = Union @ data[[2]]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 5}

```
pos = Flatten /@ Map[Position[data[[2]], #] &, union]
```

> {{1, 4, 6, 7}, {2}, {3, 5}, {8}}

```
total = Total /@ Map[mult[[pos[[#]]]] &, Range @ Length @ pos]
```

> {2.6, 0.4, 1.2, 0}

```
Join[{union, total}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 5}, {2.6, 0.4, 1.2, 0}}

Comment: Please see my comment under Nasser's answer.  Mapping `Position` (or the equivalent) should be avoided whenever possible if performance is a concern.