# Matching list entries by two values, adding the third

Tags: list-manipulation

I have data in form of:

```
data={{1,1,3},{1,1,6},{2,1,7},{2,2,4},{2,1,1}};
```

I want to match the entries with the same first two elements and add the third element in matching entries, so the result would be:

```
result={{1,1,9},{2,1,8},{2,2,4}}
```

For now, this is accomplished by using matching rules, like this:

```
data//.{h___, {x_, y_, z_}, b___, {x_, y_, f_}, t___} :> {h, {x, y, z + f}, b, t};
```

Needless to say, the procedure gets painfully slow with lists longer than a few hundred entries. 
I'm trying to come up with faster alternatives, I already looked at the examples with 1 matching element, but I can't quite expand it to two elements as I'm still fairly unfamiliar with all the operators and procedures.

Regards, blairo

Comment: How about `KeyValueMap[Append, GroupBy[data, Take[#, 2] &, Total[#[[All, -1]]] &]]`?

Comment: @J.M. unfortunately, I'm limited to V10.0.

Comment: @J.M. no `#` example: `KeyValueMap[Append, GroupBy[data, Most, Last@*Total]]`

Comment: See also: [(17734)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17734/121)

Comment: @Kuba, that'll work, but I feel that `Last@*Total` wastes a few additions.

Comment: @J.M. fine, take that then: `Tr@*Last@*Transpose` :)