# Symmetric icons

Tags: plotting, color, image, fractals

I'm trying to replicate "symmetric icons" from this book:

[https://www.amazon.com/Symmetry-Chaos-Search-Pattern-Mathematics/dp/0898716721](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0898716721)

Here is what I have so far:

```
n = 6;
α = 5;
β = 1.5;
γ = 1;
ω = 0;
λ = -2.7;
f[z_] := (λ + α z Conjugate[z] + β Re[z^n] + ω I)z + γ Conjugate[z]^(n - 1);
z0 = .1 +.1 I;
(*data=NestList[f,z0,100000];*)
ListPlot[
  {Re[#], Im[#]}& /@ NestList[f, z0, 100000],
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  Axes -> False,
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.45], White, Small},
  Background -> Black]
```

I have two questions:

1) I have a vague idea that instead of using `ListPlot`, I can use `Image` and then map the points to pixels, counting the number of times a pixel is hit, and then coloring each pixel somehow using `ColorFunction`.  However, I'm not real sure.

2) To make the image above nicer, you should change 100000 to a million, or ten million, and make the `Opacity` lower. However, I worry that I'm being very inefficient. Is there an obvious way to make this much more efficient?

#### Edit

From the help below, the "best" code I have for this is:

```
f[z_] = (λ + α z Conjugate[z] + β Re[z^n] + ω I)z + γ Conjugate[z]^(n - 1);
z0 = .1 + .1 I;
iter = 10000000;
opac=.1;
Graphics[
  {Black, Opacity[opac], PointSize[Tiny], Point[ReIm @ NestList[f, z0, iter]]}]
```

producing

[image]

I would like to be able to "simply" add custom colors (based on the number of times a neighborhood is hit by a point in the iteration) to an `Image` like this:

```
res = 1000;
colorLim = 1;
dataBin = 
  Map[GrayLevel, 
    Sqrt[(1/colorLim) * 
      Transpose @ 
        BinCounts[
          {Re[#],Im[#]}&/ @ NestList[f, z0, 1000000], 
          {-1, 1, 1/res}, {-1, 1,1/res}]], 
    {2}];
Image[dataBin]
```

but this is eluding me right now.

Comment: Note: `Re[#], Im[#]} &` can be replaced with `ReIm`.

Comment: Thanks! Currently the "best" code I know for this is has been edited above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dat = Quiet@ReIm@NestList[f, z0, 10000000];
```

#### Binning

Using the method from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17742/125) for bin counts:

```
res = 1000; 
epsilon = 1*^-10;
indices = 1 + Floor[(1 - epsilon) res Rescale[dat]];
System`SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}];
matrix = SparseArray[indices -> 1., {res, res}];
System`SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> First}];
```

#### [`Image`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html)

You can play with different scalings for bincounts:

```
Image[1 - Rescale[matrix^(1/4)], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Image[Map[Blend[{ Red, Orange, Yellow,  White}, #^4] &, 
  1 - Rescale[Normal[matrix]^(1/4)], {2}], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

#### [`MatrixPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPlot.html)

```
 MatrixPlot[Rescale[matrix^(1/4)], ImageSize -> Large, 
  MaxPlotPoints -> Infinity, Frame -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Add the option `ColorRules -> {0. -> Black}` to get

[image]

#### [`ComplexListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexListPlot.html)

```
ComplexListPlot[NestList[f, z0, 50000], 
  AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False, Background -> Black, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Abs[ f[# + #2 I]]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

#### [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) + [`VertexColors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors.html)

You can post-process `ListPlot` output to add `VertexColors`:

```
{min, max} = MinMax[Abs@NestList[f, z0, 500000]]; 

ListPlot[ReIm@NestList[f, z0, 500000], AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Axes -> False, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Tiny]] /. 
 Point[x_] :>  Point[x, VertexColors -> (Opacity[.5, #] & /@ 
      ColorData[{"Rainbow", {min, max}}] /@ (Abs@f[# + I #2] & @@@ x))]
```

[image]

#### `Graphics` + `VertexColors`

```
{min, max} = MinMax[Abs@NestList[f, z0, 500000]]; 

Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny], Opacity[.5], 
  Point[#, VertexColors -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {min, max}}]/@ (Abs@f[# + I #2]&@@@#)]&[
   ReIm@NestList[f, z0, 500000]]}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: This is really great, I love the colors, but I would like to set the color by the number of times a neighborhood is hit by a point in the iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick-and-dirty approach which might be helpful - but is pretty slow on reasonable image sizes (that is, could be improved):

```
With[{bc = 
    BinCounts[ReIm@data, 
     Sequence @@ ({#1, #2, (#2 - #1)/256} & @@@ 
        CoordinateBounds@ReIm@data)]}, 
  bc /. Map[
    Evaluate[# -> 
       ColorData["SunsetColors"]@
        N@CDF[HistogramDistribution@Flatten@bc, #] &], 
    Union@Flatten@bc]] // Image
```

[image: Histogram-based]

`BinCounts` is performed for a square defined by bounds of the dataset and color is assigned to each unique value in the count on basis of CDF of the distribution of these values. In this case `ColorData["SunsetColors"]` is used as a palette, but something custom could be used as well.

Something similar can be also achieved by "gamma-correcting" the range of bin counts. This is dramatically faster for a reason or another:

```
With[{bc = 
    BinCounts[ReIm@data, 
     Sequence @@ ({#1, #2, (#2 - #1)/256} & @@@ 
        CoordinateBounds@ReIm@data)]}, 
  Map[
   ColorData["SunsetColors"],
   (bc/N@Max@Flatten@bc)^(1/5), {2}]] // Image
```

[image: Gamma corrected]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you had `data =  NestList[f, z0, 10000000]`.

Then you might want `DensityHistogram[ReIm@data, 100, "PDF"]` or something similar, playing around with the `ColorFunction` option.

[image: densityhistogram]

Comment: I think this is actually the answer I'm looking for. However, I am unable to set the function for the coloring that will yield anything as interesting as the grayscale picture above.  

I think this is the answer, but I am unable to use it to produce the desired graph.

Comment: Crank up the number of bins.  With 2^8 bins, I get wispy structure like your example, but to get it to look 'nice' may require a lot more data and a lot more bins (read: rendering time).