# Combining the second elements of a set of ordered pairs based on their first element

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a large set of ordered pairs and I am trying to add the second elements together for any group of pairs that has the same first element.

For example my data looks like:

```
data={{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{3,2},{3,6}}
```

and I want to return something like:

```
newdata={{1,5},{2,3},{3,8}}
```

I figured out how to group the data based on their first element using
`GatherBy[data,{First}]`, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

I feel like there is probably a much easier way than that, but it is evading me.

Comment: Also see: [(16507)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16507/121)

Answer (score 9):

```
data = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {3, 6}}
{#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ GatherBy[data, First]
```

> {{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {3, 8}}

But it isn't very sophisticated.

Comment: Doesn't it seem like there is a more sophisticated way somewhere? It was driving me nuts. But this method works like a charm thanks so much!

Comment: @Kathryn Use [`Reap` and `Sow`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26579/52); they're built for this type of gather and transform problem.

Comment: Equivalently: `{1, Length[#]} Mean[#] & /@ GatherBy[data, First]`.

Comment: @0x4A4D But in this case it calculates `Total` and twice `Length`, not much but I think more. However, I like it.

Answer (score 7):

```
newData = Map[{#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[;; , 2]]]} &, GatherBy[data, First[#] &]];
```

Explaination: `GatherBy[data, First[#] &]` makes a list of all the elements in `data`, that have the same first element. Now, we apply the function `{#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[;; , 2]]]} &` by using `Map` to to take the first part of the first element of each list and then the sum of all the second parts.

**EDIT**

It seems that the `reap`and `sow` approach from above is much slower:

```
n = 1000000;
data = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {n, 2}];
Map[{#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[;; , 2]]]} &, GatherBy[data, First[#] &]]; // AbsoluteTiming
Reap[Sow[#2, #1] & @@@ data, _, {#1, Total[#2]} &][[2]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

{0.180010, Null}

{1.375079, Null}

Comment: Thanks for your quick and helpful answer! My data is sorted as needed.

Comment: On a small list, $10^6$ is not small, it doesn't matter. But, for quick solutions without much additional work, `Reap` and `Sow` are perfect for it. btw, +1.

Comment: I added some timing data to my answer, alongside an explanation as to why it occurs that way.

Answer (score 7):

This is easy to do with `Reap` and `Sow`,

```
Reap[Sow[#2, #1] & @@@ data, _, {#1, Total[#2]} &][[2]]
```

`Sow` tags the second element of the each datum with the first element, and `Reap` gathers them up, and using the last parameter, they're recombined.

For the curious, the function `{#1, Total[#2]} &` is passed the tag as the first parameter - in this case, the common first element of each datum, and a list of all the elements with that tag as the second parameter.

---

As Frederik [points out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26577/52), this solutions is not the fastest, so here is a timing comparison. To get the timings, I used the following function:

```
ClearAll[timingF];
SetAttributes[timingF, HoldAll];
timingF[expr_, threshold_: 1] := 
 Block[{time = 0, it = 0},
  While[ time <= threshold, 
   ++it;
   time += AbsoluteTiming[expr][[1]]
   ];
  time/it
  ]
```

which runs any `expr` that takes less time than some `threshold` multiple times until that threshold is reached. Then, by taking the average, the inherent jitter in small timings is reduced.

Based on the data, I added one additional example:

```
Reap[Sow[#[[2]], #[[1]]] & /@ data, _, {#1, Total[#2]} &][[2]]
```

which I will explain why in a moment. I ran the three functions with data sets as large as $10^7$ elements, and here are their timings:

[image]

In casual use, below $10^5$ elements the difference between the functions won't be noticeable, and at 100 elements and below my original function competes favorably with Frederik's. But, above 100 elements, Frederik's function becomes much faster. 100 elements is the default length for [auto-compilation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1816/52) to kick-in, so it is the inspiration for the `Map` form of `Reap`. But, `Sow` is not [compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/52), so it is slower than using `Apply` (`@@@`), in this case. An interesting thing to note, though, is all three functions scale almost linearly with input size above $10^4$ elements.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is quite fast, but not as fast as Frederik's:

```
s[p_] := Module[{ f},
  f[_] = 0;
  Scan[f@#[[1]] += #[[2]] &, p];
  f
  ]
k = s[points];
ListLinePlot[{#, k@#} & /@ points[[All, 1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: No, I was wrong; it works. I just read the code and evaluated in my head. I figured `f` would be cleared because it is `Temporary`, but forgot that only those module variables that are not returned are cleared. So this should work.

Comment: @rm-rf Yours, it's a [lazy evaluator.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)

Comment: "I just read the code and evaluated in my head" @Mr.Wizard has to add it to his quotes set. :D

Comment: @Kuba Frogs have a strange anatomy configuration, you know. I've heard tadpoles eat `Pi` quadratures for breakfast

Comment: @Kuba BTW, do you have anay relationship with this guy? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryogo_Kubo

Comment: @belisarius :p Kuba = James/Jacob :)

Comment: @belisarius He is an $n$th generation descendent of the famous Polish explorer, Stanislaw Kuba who discovered Cuba.