# Wrong Cashflow of Annuity with initial payment

Tags: bugs, finance

**Bug intoduced in (8.0?) persisting through version 13.2**

---

If we use `TimeValue` to look at the PV of an `Annuity` with initial payment:

```
TimeValue[ Annuity[{ 1, { p, 0 } }, 2], r ] // Apart
```

> $p + \frac{1}{(1+r)^2} + \frac{1}{1+r}$

The initial payment `p` is taken to be at time 0. However if we take the `Cashflow` of the same `Annuity` and look at the PV of that `Cashflow`:

```
TimeValue[ Cashflow @ Annuity[{ 1, { p, 0 } }, 2], r ] // Apart
```

> $\frac{1}{(1+r)^2} + \frac{1+p}{1+r}$

Suddenly `p` is now taken to be at time 1 instead of 0. Is this a bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Mathematica is quite clearly adding the initial payment to the first period rather than at t=0. Output `Out[18]` above should be `Cashflow[{{0, p}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}}]`

Comment: Yes, and it would be convenient that way to have initial payment at 0. BTW my version is 10.0.2.0. I don't know the behavior of previous versions.

Comment: Bug report submitted to WRI.

Comment: Please post code in text form, per site formatting help, rather than images of code!

Comment: Looks like nobody at WRI cares to fix this rather simple bug. Sad. :)

Comment: As a workaround and in general I would always use `Cashflow` to make the payments and times more visible (as suggested by Mike). Then using the functionality shown [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138644/764) you can always construct complicated cashflows by adding and subtracting individual cashflows, e.g. `cashflow = Cashflow[ Annuity[ 1, 5]  ] + Cashflow[ {p} ]`.

Comment: I just noticed this in version 12.3. When I went to post about it I found this earlier post. This bug will result in a wrong result in a financial calculation. Why hasn't it been fixed?

Comment: Still persisting in v13.1

Comment: It is ridiculous this bug has persisted for 7+ years now. If it is of any use, the case number was CASE:2800989 in whatever issue tracking system Wolfram Research was using back then.

Comment: I even scavenged out the email reply I got at the time, it said _"It does appear that the Cashflow function is not behaving properly in this case and I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided."_ -- So you see, there's a middle layer between the actual bug and the developpers. This stands in contrast with the Open Source model, where bug reports are directly sent to the dev team and are immediately viewable by everyone.

Comment: @asterix314 it is possible that the person who wrote this initially has left WRI and no one there understands the code fully to fix it without introducing new bug. May be if it is complex code. This happens all the time at large software companies. May be this is why it has not been fixed yet?. Just guessing ofcourse.

Comment: @Nasser This happens all the time, true, but I can't believe it's the case for this one. MMA's QA is generally sound, and `CashFlow` is far from being the most complex function. That's why this bug doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WRI replied, finally:

> We believe that the issue has been resolved in the current 13.2.1
> release of Mathematica.

I don't have the newest version installed so I cannot verify. But I think we can take their word and consider the issue closed.

Comment: I can confirm that `TimeValue[Annuity[{1, {p, 0}}, 2], r] // Apart` and 
`TimeValue[Cashflow@Annuity[{1, {p, 0}}, 2], r] // Apart` both yield
(*p + 1/(1 + r)^2 + 1/(1 + r)*) at v.13.2.1

Comment: What's that? 13 years later? I got an email from them 5 years after I reported a bug, telling me it had been fixed. I wonder what their mean bug-fix time is...

Comment: Better later than never - you are welcome :)