# Compute intermediate totals using Select and Plus in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have to total per year of weekly results of a function which are in a table with 3 rows: one with the result of the function, one with the week number and one with the year number. I am almost sure that combining Select and Total should do it. I didn't find any example (maybe i didn't look well enough) in StackExchange...
Edit:
Here is a minimal example of the data:

```
(-429446.   15. 1984.
337.724 16. 1984.
155953. 17. 1984.
221679. 18. 1984.
81618.2 19. 1984.
-420619.    20. 1984.
-870370.    21. 1984.
-902968.    22. 1984.
-873332.    23. 1984.
-602452.    24. 1984.)
```

Comment: Could you please provide some additional information to your original post? Like - what is the data? What is the desired output format? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes, the data is in the form:{{-429134,15,1984},{-112345,16,1984},...{213420,35,2015}} And I tried Table[Select[Total[sTT[[#, 1]]], sTT[[#,3]] == i &], {i, 1984, 2013}]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the input and the desired output. Any code you have writen would also be very much appreciated.

Comment: I need to sum all data of the same year which are in the first column of the matrix which is 735 rows and 3 columns

Comment: How about: [26574](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26574/5478) and linked topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is called `L`, this should work:

```
Transpose[{#[[All, 1, 2]], Total[#[[All, All, 1]], {2}]}] &[GatherBy[L[[All, {1, 3}]], Last]]
```

More neat though:

```
Map[Total[L[[#, 1]]] &, PositionIndex[L[[All, 3]]]]

(*To convert to list*)
List @@@ Normal[%]
```

Comment: I get a Lists of unequal length in Internal`PartitionRagged as output.

Comment: @Xavier_B I edited, does the new thing work?

Comment: Yes, it does! Fantastic! I wish I kew Mathematica as you do!

Comment: This is great, a slightly shorter version would be:  `{#[[1, 3]], First@Total@#} & /@ GatherBy[L, Last]`

Answer (score 2):

**Example:**

```
(*pseudo data*)
data = {{-429134, 15, 1984}, {-112345, 16, 1984}, {213420, 35, 2015}}

(*operation*)
f[year_] := Total @ (First @ # & /@ Select[data, Last[#] == year &])
f[#] & /@ {1984, 2015}
```

**Output:**

> {-541479, 213420}

**Reference:**

[@ /@ # etc.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616)
[First](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html)
[Last](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Last.html)
[Select](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html?q=Select)

Comment: Works also, but still needs to tierate on the year from 1984 to 2015

Comment: @Xavier_B please see edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you have version 10, you can also use [GroupBy](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html):

```
data={{a, w1, y1}, {b, w2, y1},  {c, w1, y2}, {d, w2, y2}, {e, w3, y2}, {f, w4, y3}};
List@@@Normal@GroupBy[data, Last->First, Total]
```

> {{y1,a+b}, {y2,c+d+e}, {y3,f}}