# List rearrangment with joining of strings

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a list of strings:

```
lis = {{"a","b","x"},{"d","e","y"},{"a","b","z"},{"d","c","x"},{"a","b","w"}}
```

I would like to use StringJoin on the last elements where initial elements are the same to obtain:

```
res = {{"a","b","xzw"},{"d","e","y"},{"d","c","x"}}
```

Doing:

```
lis = SortBy[lis, {#[[1]]} &]
SequenceCases[lis, {{a_, b_, c_}, {a_, b_, d_}} :> {a, b, StringJoin[c, d]}]
```

only gives:

```
{{"a", "b", "wx"}}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: At least closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26574/5478

Comment: @Suite401, do you have control on how the "initials" are generated? If they where integers (which can be achieved with `ToCharacterCode`), then I could also image faster methods.

Comment: @Henrik, Each actual element of the list looks like:  {DateObject,String,String representation of integer,String,String representation of integer,String,String,String} so I'm not sure there's much to be done, but am interested in your thoughts.

Comment: Okay, my idea would have required that the number of keys is known a priorily. Btw., I found out that Carl Woll's code is much faster than mine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another variation:

```
KeyValueMap[Append] @ GroupBy[lis, Most->Last, StringJoin]
```

> {{"a", "b", "xzw"}, {"d", "e", "y"}, {"d", "c", "x"}}

although you may like just the output of `GroupBy[lis, Most->Last, StringJoin]` better.

Answer (score 4):

```
KeyValueMap[
 {key, value} \[Function] Join[key, {StringJoin[value]}],
 GroupBy[lis, Part[#, 1 ;; 2] & -> Last]
 ]
```

> {{"a", "b", "xzw"}, {"d", "e", "y"}, {"d", "c", "x"}}

Comment: That's probably the first time I've seen anyone use the infix function notation here. I forgot that even existed.

Comment: @Sjoerd Actually, I use it quite often...

Answer (score 4):

Another one:

```
 KeyValueMap[Append] @ Merge[StringJoin][ {#, #2} -> #3 & @@@ lis ]
```

Comment: Thanks Henrik, Kuba; am checking to see which is faster on big data set