# Merging pairs of a list with keeping the first elements and adding the second elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list that was generated by the below code:

```
Do[
 Do[
  AppendTo[list, {RandomInteger[i], RandomInteger[j]}, 
  {i, 1, 5}
 ], 
 {j, 1, 5}
]
```

A result can be produced as :

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 1},
 {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 0}, 
 {1, 0}, {1, 12}, {2, 0}, {4, 2}, {5, 3}, 
 {0, 4}, {2,4}, {0, 2}, {4, 1}, {3, 1},
 {1, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 3}, {1, 1}, {3, 2}}
```

I wish to merge all pairs whose first elements are the same. Provided that the first element must be kept and the second elements must be accumulated. There is an answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26574/combining-the-second-elements-of-a-set-of-ordered-pairs-based-on-their-first-ele) but I do not have the list at final end, and I have to access the result in any iteration

For example at the first I have

```
{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}}
```

and after theses and for next iteration, I have to have:

```
{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 0}}
```

and next iteration:

```
 {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 0}}
```

and so on...I know that I can use `Accumulate` but I do not know where I must make use of them!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[foldGroupBy]

foldGroupBy = FoldList[
     KeyValueMap[List][GroupBy[Append @ ##, First -> Last, Total]] &, 
    {First @ #}, Rest @ #] &;

foldGroupBy @lst // Column
```

***Example:***

```
lst = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {4, 2}, 
  {5, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 12}, {2, 0}, {4, 2}, {5, 3}, {0, 4}, {2,4}, {0, 2}, {4, 1},
  {3, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 3}, {1, 1}, {3, 2}};

foldGroupBy @ lst // Column
```

[image]

Also:

```
ClearAll[mapGroupBy]
mapGroupBy[data_] := KeyValueMap[List][
  GroupBy[Take[data, #], First -> Last, Total]] & /@ Range[Length@data]

ClearAll[mapMerge]
mapMerge[data_] := KeyValueMap[List]@
    Merge[Total][Take[Association @* Rule @@@ data, #]] & /@ Range[Length @ data]
```

and based on [Kuba's answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26574/combining-the-second-elements-of-a-set-of-ordered-pairs-based-on-their-first-ele)

```
ClearAll[mapGatherBy] 
mapGatherBy[data_] := {#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ 
    GatherBy[Take[data, #], First] & /@ Range[Length @ data]

foldGroupBy@lst == mapMerge @ lst == mapGroupBy @ lst  == mapGatherBy @ lst
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A less tricky way:

```
res = Association[];
ans = Reap[
    Table[{i, j} = m;
    res[i] = Lookup[res, i, 0] + j;
    res // # /. Rule | Association :> List & // Sow, {m, lst}]
    ] // Flatten[#, 1] &;
ans // Drop[#, -1] & // Column
```

Comment: This idea comes from python`res = defaultdict(int);for i, j in li:    res[i] += j
    print(res.items())`