# Problem averaging multiple series of data

Tags: list-manipulation

Recently I'm having trouble figuring out a certain problem in Mathematica. I have a table of data in the following arrangement:

{series no., x, y}

Now, each series of data has exactly the same x values, with different y. What I am trying to achieve is averaging the y values for all series of data for each x, so that the final table looks like this:

{x, average y}

Do you have any ideas on how to solve it efficiently?

Comment: The difference is you have to use `Mean` instead of `Total` because the linked topic is about sum.

Comment: Greetings! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: [Combining the second elements of a set of ordered pairs based on their first element](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26574/5478) and [How to sum over duplicates?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16507/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say this is your data:

```
data = Transpose@{RandomInteger[10, 20], RandomInteger[5, 20], RandomReal[1, 20]};

TableForm[data, TableHeadings -> Automatic]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) to get only `x` and `y` part and [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) to gather by  `x`

```
GatherBy[Part[data, All, {2, 3}], First]
```

> ```
>  {
>     {{0, 0.554355}, {0, 0.669234}, {0, 0.673409}}
>   , {{3, 0.107376}, {3, 0.535935}, {3, 0.836943}, {3, 0.479782}, {3, 0.176511}, {3, 0.966172}, {3, 0.896234}, {3, 0.784782}}
>   , {{2, 0.319966}, {2, 0.0572314}, {2, 0.450977}}
>   , {{5, 0.980007}, {5, 0.49463}}
>   , {{1, 0.0754787}, {1, 0.307566}, {1, 0.77322}}
>   , {{4, 0.656813}}
>    }
> ```

Now you only need to [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) the [`Mean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) over the list

```
Mean /@ GatherBy[Part[data, All, {2, 3}], First]
```

> ```
> {
>    {0, 0.632333}
>  , {3, 0.597967}
>  , {2, 0.276058}
>  , {5, 0.737318}
>  , {1, 0.385422}
>  , {4, 0.656813}
>  }
> ```

You can create a function that does that for later use

```
avgx[data_] := Map[Mean, GatherBy[Part[data, All, {2, 3}], First]]
```