# Filter through list and lump data

Tags: list-manipulation, data, iterators

I have a very large data set (around 3000) that looks like:

```
{{1749.08, 580.}, {1749.17, 626.}, {1749.25, 700.}, {1749.33, 
  557.}, {1749.42, 850.}, {1749.5, 835.}, {1749.58, 948.}, {1749.67, 
  663.}....
```

The first number is the year plus the month/12. So I want to iterate over all the list adding the second part for each year

So example using data above:

`For year 1749:
580+626+700+557+850+835+948+663`

I know I have to use a for loop but I can't figure out the syntax. Can anyone lend a helping hand?

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate, with the exception of the need to `Round` (or `Floor`) the first column data.  I have marked it as such.  If anyone disagrees please comment and/or vote to reopen.

Comment: Closely related: [(4332)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4332/121)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to gather the years by using `Floor` and then adding up the values for each year.

```
data = {{1749.08, 580.}, {1749.17, 626.}, {1749.25, 
    700.}, {1749.33, 557.}, {1749.42, 850.}, {1749.5, 835.}, {1749.58,
     948.}, {1749.67, 663.}, {1750.00, 653.}};
Total[Part[#, All, 2]] & /@ GatherBy[data, Floor[First[#]] &]
(* {5759., 653.} *)
```

Comment: This works great, but I'm a little confused as to why for this output it has the `653`?

Comment: @user1985351 I added a fake value for the year 1750 as last element in `data`. So what you see is the sum of all entries for the year 1749 and the sum for all entries of the year 1750.

Comment: Oh I see that now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{1749.08, 580.}, {1749.17, 626.}, {1749.25, 700.}, {1749.33, 
   557.}, {1749.42, 850.}, {1749.5, 835.}, {1749.58, 948.}, {1749.67, 
   663.}, {1751.66, 10}, {1751.77, 20}}

Total /@ GatherBy[data, IntegerPart[#[[1]]] &][[All, All, 2]]

(* {5759.,30} *)
```

Note the data might be a bit ambiguous: if the month is 12, the year gets bumped to the next. Is that really what you want?