# Let's do this list-rearrangement prettier

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, functional-style

Suppose that i have a list in this format=

$list=\{ \{a,obj1 \} ,\{c,obj2 \}, \{a,obj3 \}, \{b,obj4 \} \dots\}$

I want to construct a new list in this way:

$ newlist= \{ \{ \{a,obj1\} , \{a,obj3\} ... \}, \{ \{b,obj4\} , \{b,obj5\} ... \} ...\} $

This is, the new list must have sublist in which the first element of each sub-element is the same. In this way we have that for example, the first element of $newlist$ is formed by all the pairs in the form $\{a, [] \}$, the second element is formed by all the pairs in the form $\{b, [] \}$ ...etc.

My current approach is the following:

- Use $elements=Union[list[[All,1]] ]$ to get all different first-elements.
- Use $Select$ to get all elements of $list$ that has the same first-element extracted from $elements$.
- Construct a new list combining the two points.

What I whant is a "clever" functional-programming way to achieve this using the fewest functions possible.

I believe that this is an interesting question for people that are learning functional-programming (as me, for example).

Comment: This question is a simplistic version of: [(4332)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4332/121)

Comment: Yeah @Mr.Wizard, and it turns it is not as interesting as I thought so as i said in other comment: Sorry for the is-in-the-help-question. :( (Also, i tried to find another similar question but the use of "columns" in the other question made my search not as productive as i wanted to....sorry again).

Comment: It is okay.  Thank you for searching before posting.  FYI: my comment above was not intended to denigrate your question but only to help you or others find related questions. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GatherBy` does exactly what you want.

```
l = {{a, obj1}, {c, obj2}, {a, obj3}, {b, obj4}};
GatherBy[l, First]
```

> {{{a, obj1}, {a, obj3}}, {{c, obj2}}, {{b, obj4}}}

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. Sometimes is hard to search within the help and not get lost. Sorry for the is-in-the-help-question.