# Average list of list of parameter values

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of lists of fitted parameter values, e.g.

```
list={{a->1,b->10},{a->2,b->20},{a->3,b->30}}
```

(the actual parameter names can vary, as well as the size of the list)

What is the easiest way then to obtain the average parameter values, in this case
`avg={a->2,b->20}` ?

Comment: Also: [(4332)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4332/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Normal@Merge[Mean][list]
(* {a -> 2, b -> 20} *)
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks a lot!!

Comment: This is nifty: is it efficient? What if the list is very very long? Does going through Association have a penalty?

Comment: @Tom, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: @chris, good question. I am not sure about the relative efficiency. It would be a good idea to do timing comparisons after a few more alternatives come in.

Answer (score 1):

A method that works on older versions of Mathematica is this:

```
{a, b} -> Map[Mean, Transpose[{a, b} /. list]]
```

but admittedly it won't be as fast as `Merge`.