# Group matrix values by column

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, gathering

Original Question:
I have a list `{{a, 1}, {b, 3}, {c, 1}, {d, 2}, {e, 3}}`. I want to be able to group the the first number in each pair that has the same second number in the pair. So i would get a list like

`{{a,c},d,{b,e}}` so

`{a,c}` is from `{a,1}` and `{c,1}`

`d` is from `{d,2}`

`{b,e}` is from `{b,3}` and `{e,3}`

Comment: If you have V10+ take a look at `GroupBy`, otherwise `GatherBy` documentation.

Comment: See also [(4332)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4332/121) and its many Linked questions.

Comment: Your update seems to change the question substantially.  (It makes the answer that you accepted incorrect.)   You should instead ask a new question.  (BTW, it appears that answer to your new question is `DeleteCases[0] /@ Transpose[matrix]`.)

Comment: `Transpose[matrix] /. 0 -> Nothing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what you need:

```
SortBy[GatherBy[list,Last],Last@*Last][[;;,;;,1]]/.{x_?AtomQ}->x
```

The result is:

```
{{a,c},d,{b,e}}
```

This will gather the elements by the last member of each small list, sort it by the index number and then throw away all the index numbers. Finally, it can change all one element list into the number itself.

Will this help directly?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark oh yes! I mistype it cause I'm currently typing with my tiny phone on my hand. Thanks for informing!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand. Here are some ways to group by last element:

```
list={{1, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}}
GatherBy[list, Last]
GroupBy[list, Last]
Last@Reap[Sow[{##}, #2] & @@@ list, _, Rule]
```

yielding respectively:

```
{{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 2}}}

<|1 -> {{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, 3 -> {{1, 3}, {2, 3}}, 2 -> {{2, 2}}|>

{1 -> {{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, 3 -> {{1, 3}, {2, 3}}, 2 -> {{2, 2}}}
```

`GroupBy` has other useful features.

Comment: Probably `GroupBy[list, Last -> First]` with skiping `{}` from one element lists. Not so sure about an order and its meaning.

Comment: I don't mind the extra {}. But how do i use this as a list it has the weird form `<|1 -> {1, 2}, 3 -> {1, 2}, 2 -> {2}|>`

Comment: @MTR that is an `Association` (see documentation), You can "normalize" it  with `Normal@GroupBy[list,Last]`.

Comment: @MTR or `Values @ GroupBy[list, Last -> First]`