# List of tuples: group by first element of tuple; sum up the second element per group

Tags: list-manipulation

Imagine following list

```
list = {{0, 3}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}
```

I would like to get the result

```
{{0, 3}, {1, 3}, {2, 7}}
```

i.e., grouping by the first element of the tuples in the list, summing the second element of all tuples that share the same first element.

Comment: Try `KeyValueMap[List, Total /@ GroupBy[list, First -> Last]]`.

Comment: @J.M. `GroupBy` also accepts a reduce argument, even simpler then `KeyValueMap[List, GroupBy[list, First -> Last, Total]]`

Comment: @swish, ah, that's even better!

Comment: `{#1[[1, 1]], Total[#[[2]]]} & /@ Transpose /@ GatherBy[list, First]` works in versions older than V10.

Comment: `{#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ GatherBy[list, First]`

Comment: This is already covered in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60205/121) (mine) so I am marking this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summary of the methods given in the comments to the question.

```
data = {{0, 3}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}};
```

**swish** (requires V10 or later)

```
KeyValueMap[List, GroupBy[data, First -> Last, Total]]
```

**m_goldberg** (requires V7 or later)

```
{#1[[1, 1]], Total[#[[2]]]} & /@ Transpose /@ GatherBy[data, First]
```

**Mr.Wizard**

```
Rule @@@ list // Merge[Total] // KeyValueMap[List]
```

All the above return

> ```
> {{0, 3}, {1, 3}, {2, 7}}
> ```