# Conditional union of a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

With a nested list such as

```
listA = {{{a,b,c},{1,0,0}}, {{a,b,c},{0,1,0}}, {{d,e,f},{1,1,0}}};
```

How can I create

```
listB = {{{a,b,c},{{1,0,0},{0,1,0}}}, {{d,e,f},{1,1,0}}};
```

and so-forth for any length of `listA`?

Comment: At least closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4332/5478

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
KeyValueMap[List] @ GroupBy[listA, First -> Last] 
Values @ GroupBy[listA, First, {#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 2]]}&] 
KeyValueMap[List] @ Merge[Association /@ Rule @@@ listA, Identity]
{#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[listA, First]
```

all give

> {{{a, b, c}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}}, {{d, e, f}, {{1, 1, 0}}}}

Comment: Very nice and concise. And general!

Comment: @PhillipDukes, thank you for the accept.